# Foursquare API for getting details of a venue only giving two tips for venue

Tags: api, get, foursquare

I'm using Foursquare API for getting venue details, and in particular I need to collect the tips about the venue. The problem is that for any venue I'm querying, the tips listed are only two, even if the count is higher.
This is an example:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beginning on May 31st, 2018, foursquare made five changes in order to simplify their API and maintain the quality of their service as their developer community grows.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/announcements#start-up-tier-launch

> The quantity of photos and tips per venue will be changed to 1 for Sandbox Tier and 2 Personal Tier